# php remove everything after a bracket

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to save a string and the data is coming in with stuff that I don't want at the end of an array.

```
["bunch", "of", "stuff"]unwantedtext
```

I'm struggling with getting rid of everything after the closing bracket. This is my latest attempt. I end up with an empty file.

```
$toPost = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '\]'));
```

Perhaps my escape isn't working correctly? I've also tried doublequotes.

Here's an update to the original question.

This is my Javascript function:

```
goalChange = function() {
  var i, key, len, postThis;
  key = void 0;
  postThis = {};
  i = 0;
  len = localStorage.length;
  while (i < len) {
    key = localStorage.key(i);
    postThis[key] = "" + localStorage.getItem(key);
    i++;
  }
  postThis.goals = localStorage.getItem("goals");
  postThis.userid = username;
  return $.ajax({
    url: "goalChange.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: postThis,
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      return console.log("Yay, the save worked!");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      return console.log("Didn't work so good...");
    }
  });
};
```

Here's the PHP file:

```
<?
if ($_POST) {
    $user = $_POST['userid'];  // ADDED THIS LINE AND CHANGED NEXT TO GET STUFF INTO THE USERS OWN FILE
    $logFile = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . "/" . $user . ".json";
    if (!file_exists($logFile)) {
        touch($logFile);
        chmod($logFile, 0777);
    }
    $newStr = ($_POST);
    $str = str_replace('\\', '', $newStr);
    $toPost = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, ']'));
    file_put_contents($logFile, $toPost);
    echo "OK";
    return;
}
```

I need to use the userid to save the file with the correct name. That's working, but the file is getting the userid added to the end of the array that I want to keep.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would look into how that unwanted text is getting there in the first place. Fix the problem, don't make a workaround.

Comment: @JustinWood Yeah that's my plan, but I got curious about figuring out how to use strrpos and got my self stumped on this side issue. Once I saw that the available questions/answers here didn't hit on this exact problem it might be worth having answered.

Comment: If you show us how you are getting that array and text, we may be able to guide you in removing it.

Answer (score 3):

try..

```
$text = '["bunch", "of", "stuff"]unwantedtext';
$text = substr($text,0, strpos($text,"]")+1 );

echo $text;
```

i don't get it.. you want to check a 'json' file (for example) and ..get only the '[]' stuff?

```
<?php
$text = '["bunch", "of", "stuff"]unwantedtext ["bunchssdfs", "of", "stuxxxff"]dsfadffs';
preg_match_all("#(\[)(.*?)(\])#isU", $text, $matches);

if( sizeof( $matches ) > 0 ){
    $myMatches = $matches[0];
    echo implode(PHP_EOL,$matches[0]); // show matches..
}
```

Comment: It's beginning to feel like I didn't ask my question properly. This gives me the capital letter A for the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear, but judging by the code, you are trying to save the `$_POST` variable as a json string.

If that is the case, please don't generate the json manually, use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) instead:

```
if ($_POST) {
    $user = $_POST['userid'];  // ADDED THIS LINE AND CHANGED NEXT TO GET STUFF INTO THE USERS OWN FILE
    $logFile = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . "/" . $user . ".json";
    if (!file_exists($logFile)) {
        touch($logFile);
        chmod($logFile, 0777);
    }

    file_put_contents($logFile, json_encode($_POST));

    echo "OK";
}
```

Please note that you need to check the return value from your ajax call to determine if the save really worked. The `success` function in your javascript is called when a successfull request to the server was made, regardless of the outcome.

Comment: Hmmm, well, the $_Post variable is already a json string. So when I try the json_encode it wraps it all as an object and then also sticks the userid inside the object. I just want the array without the userid at the end.

Comment: @charliemagee No, the `$_POST` variable is an array and you cannot treat it like a string. If you need to remove the user ID, simply `unset()` it in the array before you use `json_encode`.

Comment: well slap myself upside the head. I knew the first bit was an array but didn't realize that adding the userid was simply adding to the array. I used array_pop to get rid of it. Worked a charm. Thanks. Shouldn't this be created as an answer rather than buried in the comments?

Comment: @charliemagee Good to hear! The answer (`json_encode`) is really all there is to it, and even that does not answer your original question as you put it :-)